# How do I style each option in select to use a different font (using materialize css framework)

Tags: html, css, materialize

I want to style each option in select to use a different font family in materialize css framework
shown in [this](https://ibb.co/tDqq17z) img url
I have achieved this by styling each option with an id got from using inspect element but that does not stay and resets when the browser is refreshed 
id is auto generated and looks like this

```
li#select-options-5ea35c39-e3ba-6859-c611-43359ab710b32{
font-family: 'Homemade Apple', cursive !important;
font-size: 25px;}
```

Things I have tried

1. Using different class/id on each option and styling it in css with !important but that doesn't override default styling.
2. Using `.dropdown-content, .select-dropdown` classes but this style the whole thing not individual
3. Using `.select-dropdown li>span` this also style everything in the select

Comment: which javascript framework are you using ?

Comment: materialize JS (to implement materialize select style) and vanilla JS for my own functions

Comment: will a JS based solution do ? or are you looking for proper CSS one ?

Comment: Yes I can try to implement JS solution.. Please guide me with DOM related solution

Answer (score 2, accepted):

@kushal It worked thanks.. now I got it.. I targeted span element after every nth-child

```
.select-dropdown>li:nth-child(2)>span{
font-family: 'Indie Flower', cursive;
font-size: 1.5em;
color: black;
}
.select-dropdown>li:nth-child(3)>span{
font-family: 'Dawning of a New Day', cursive;
font-size: 1.8em;
color: blue;
}
```

And so on..
Here is the result
https://ibb.co/gvfMyWq

Answer (score 1):

You can use this in your css

```
:nth-child(number) {
  css declarations;
}
```

Here you can use the main class as prefix like if you are using a paragraph tag you can use like

```
p:nth-child(2) {
  background: red;
}
```

Here child is the number so in your list first item is the first number like wise you can arrange it...!!

Hope you get some spark from this...!!

Let me know if it worked...!!

Comment: Alright glad it worked..!! can you upvote my answer :)

Answer (score 0):

vanilla JS solution ([demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/vanilla-js-playground-dtzswf?file=index.html))

```
<ul>
    <li id="select-options-123">cursive</li>
    <li id="select-options-456">fantasy</li>
    <li id="select-options-789">monospace</li>
</ul>

<script> 
  var selector = "li[id*='select-options-']";
  document
    .querySelectorAll(selector)
    .forEach(el => el.style.fontFamily = el.textContent);
</script>
```